# UITextView text indicator in the wrong place

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I'm having an issue trying to have a consistent view of my uitextview.

when it appears on my view that blue indicator stay out of it content

[image]

but when I start typing it goes to the right place

[image]

also when I delete the text that happens:[image]

Thats 's the code that configures my text view:

```
    textView.delegate = self
    textView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    textView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
    textView.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    textView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 4,left: 4,bottom: 4,right: 4)
    textView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

I added it to my view will appear. Don't know why it is happening.

Answer (score -1):

"UIEdgeInsets" have 4 points from all side so it creates an issue for the indicator. so plz fix 0.5 it's working fine. otherwise, open storyboard and manage option.

```
textView.delegate = self
    textView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    textView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
    textView.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    textView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.5,left: 0.5,bottom: 0.5,right: 0.5)
    textView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

[Plz Check Image You should manage from here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6lBj.png)